How to access parent route loader data in react route loader?
Given this example from the react router dom docs page:
createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    loader: () => fetchUser(),
    element: <Root />,
    id: "root",
    children: [
      {
        path: "jobs/:jobId",
        loader: loadJob,
        element: <JobListing />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);

Is there a way to access the loaded data from the root path (provided by the fetchUser function) in the loadJob loader function of the child path? as loadJob is just a function and not a react hook, I cannot use useRouteLoaderData("root") there.

No, there is no way to merge data from one loader into another. Use the useRouteLoaderData hook in the JobListing component as per the documentation you linked in the post. JobListing can load other route's data in addition to its own data.
Basic Example:
import {
  useLoaderData ,
  useRouteLoaderData,
} from "react-router-dom";

const JobListing = () => {
  const jobsData = useLoaderData();            // <-- "jobs/:jobId", this route
  const userData = useRouteLoaderData("root"); // <-- "/" root route

  ...
};


Thanks for the answer. I know that I can use the hook in the component. But my question was about using the data in the loader, not the component.
The job loader needs a property of the loaded user data to be able to load the job data.

@MatterOfFact I see. You didn't specify that in your post. Can you edit the post to include all relevant details of the issue or problem you are trying to overcome?

What are you missing exactly in my question? I think I wrote exactly what I want to achieve: "Is there a way to access the loaded data from the root path (provided by the fetchUser function) in the loadJob loader function of the child path? as loadJob is just a function and not a react hook, I cannot use useRouteLoaderData("root") there."

@MatterOfFact Ok, then my answer still stands. You can't. That isn't how route loaders work. Can you edit the post to clarify what you need from the parent route's loader function in the child/nested route's loader?
